# SGDRegressor Won't Accept a List of Sparse Matrixes

Tags: python, regression, sparse-matrix

I don't have the memory to convert the entire list of sparse matrices into a numpy 2d array, and then convert that to a sparse matrix.

The regressor WILL accept the following:

```
X = sparse.csr_matrix( my_2D_Numpy_Matrix )
```

It doesn't accept (this is just an example):

```
X = []
for i in range(my_2D_Numpy_Matrix.shape[0]):
    X.append(sparse.csr_matrix(my_2D_Numpy_Matrix[i,:]))
```

Comment: Can you please post: more code, examples of `my_2D_Numpy_Matrix), `X`, etc? We need more information to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge sparse matrices without converting them to numpy matrix using `sparse.vstack`

```
X = sparse_list[0]

for mat in sparse_list[1:]:
    X = sparse.vstack((X,mat))
```

Comment: Why not just do X=sparse.vstack(sparse_list) instead of the loop?

Comment: If that works, it's indeed better solution. According to documentation it takes tuple as a argument https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html so I haven't tried that.